# AngularJS : Does ng-disabled remove input value?

Tags: angularjs, forms, input, angularjs-ng-disabled

The title says everything...
I've been reading several posts on Stackoverflow as well as [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), but I haven't found a satisfactory explanation yet.

If `ng-disabled` is activated, is the input value inside the tag removed?

Let me illustrate with an example.

```
<form method="POST" name="form" action="">
    <select ng-model="model[1]"  
            ng-options="i for i in fc.items[1]" 
            ng-disabled="true">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="model[2]" 
            ng-options="i for i in fc.items[2]" 
            ng-disabled="false">
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

The input value is `results[2]:number:1`. (`number:1` is the expected result).

When I remove `ng-disabled`, the result is `results[1]:number:1` `results[2]:number:1`.

I'm about to conclude the `ng-disabled` affects the input value, but I'd like to know if anyone here knows how to get all the input values (if it's possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Disabling an input just make it **unusable** and **unclickable**. The value still persist.

Your value is not send because **disabled  elements in a `form` will not be submitted.**

---

From W3C [Input disabling](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp):

> A disabled input element is unusable and un-clickable.
>
> The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the
>    element until some other condition has been met (like
>   selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the
>   disabled value, and make the  element usable.
>
> Tip: Disabled input elements in a form will not be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

No, It doesn't remove input value at all. It just make input inaccessible. `ng-disabled` directive just add/remove `disabled` attribute based on expression passed to it.

```
ng-disabled="expression"
```

Look at the `ngDisabled` API  for more vision [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L348-L377). Internally it calls `attr.$set(attrName, !!value)`, which decides wheather to  add/remove attribute from DOM element behind the scene from this method([Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1713-L1723)).